# How to get value of variable in object javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

I got the following lines of code:

```
 for (var i = 0; i<ke.length; i++)
        {

            var ar = ke[i];
            var temp = {ar :(n[a])}; //how to resolve a
            console.log(temp);

        }
```

temp an object which should contain a list of columnames(key) and values, but he takes a as literal, how can i fix that?  n[a] is a json object and a the colum name

```
 current output: temp = {a:["some", "value"] }

what i want: {"valueOfA" : ["some", "value"] }
```

I am normally a java developer, so js seems so strange. I hope you can help me. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You question is incomplete. Please add more details for others to understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialise temp to an empty object and then set its key value as below :

```
var temp = {};
temp[a] = // value to be stored
```

By doing so it will store the value contained in `a` as the key instead of storing `a` as a key.

Comment: that worked fine thanks. Sorry for the dumb question :)

Answer (score 1):

Look,

This is an empty javascript object:

```
var temp = {};
```

This is a javascript object with key a and value empty string:

```
var temp = {a:""};
```

if you want to get empty string (or whatever you put there, array, number etc.) you can get it like:

```
console.log(temp.a);
```

For your example, you can get the a value from there, or you can declare temp as:

```
var temp = (v[a]);
```

So, if you log temp, you will get the array from there.